# Finding common subindex values with error?

Tags: python, pandas

How would you find a common values of subindices, columns B in this example, between two dataframes where index A = 'a'?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Do': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'Ri': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Mi': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],'A':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
'B': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df.set_index(['A', 'B'])


        Do  Ri  Mi
A   B           
a   1   0   0   0
    2   0   0   0
    2   0   0   0
    3   0   0   0
b   4   0   0   0
    5   0   0   0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Do': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'Ri': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'Mi': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'A':['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
'B': [3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]})
df2.set_index(['A', 'B'])

        Do  Ri  Mi
A   B           
a   3   0   0   0
    3   0   0   0
    4   0   0   0
    6   0   0   0
b   7   0   0   0
    8   0   0   0
```

Currently I have:

```
df_a = df.loc[['a']].sort_index(level='B')
df2_a = df2.loc[['a']].sort_index(level='B')

df_a_b = df_a.index.levels[1].tolist()
df2_a_n = df2_a.index.levels[1].tolist()
set(df_a_b) & set(df2_a_n)
```

But this seems to take from where index A = 'a' and A = 'b'

I noticed that have loc['a'] or loc[['a']] results in different dfs, I'm not sure if this relates, but what is the significance of [['a']] vs ['a']?

Comment: I don't follow the logics. What's your expect outcome?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, expected would be a set of common subindex values in B taking only where index A = 'a', i.e. [3] in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single overlap use set intersection after subsetting each DataFrme:

```
set(df.loc['a'].index) & set(df2.loc['a'].index)
#{3}
```

`merge` also works, but is overkill for a single intersection. On the other hand, if you want to do all the intersections at once, then use `.merge` + `groupby`

```
#Single
df.loc['a'].merge(df2.loc['a'], left_index=True, right_index=True).index.unique()
#Int64Index([3], dtype='int64', name='B')

#All
df.merge(df2, on=['A', 'B']).reset_index().groupby('A').B.unique()
#A
#a    [3]
#Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

To explain your error, you were finding the intersection of the `levels`, but what you want is the intersection of the **level values**. Your current code should be changed to:

```
df_a = df.loc[['a']].sort_index(level='B')
df2_a = df2.loc[['a']].sort_index(level='B')

#                   Get The Level Values, not the Level IDs
df_a_b = df_a.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
df2_a_n = df2_a.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()

set(df_a_b) & set(df2_a_n)
#{3}
```

Comment: so I should havw been using set(df.loc['a'].index) & set(df2.loc['a'].index) instead of set(df.loc[['a']].index) & set(df2.loc[['a']].index)?

Comment: @RoyHan Correct. When you provide a single index slice with `.loc[ ]` you are able to select out a lower dimensional slice (in this case the index becomes only the `'B'` level. On the other hand using `.loc[[ ]]` maintains the same dimensional slice, including both `A` and `B` as index levels. However still it will work to get you the intersection. Using double brackets returns `{('a', 3)}`